# Creating an image array with next and previous buttons in Xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I am very new to iPhone dev and while going through Sams Teach Yourself iPhone App Dev in 24 Hours I have loads of questions.

Basically, I want to design an app that has anywhere from 30-100 or more images, with a previous and next button to go through them in an array.

I've looked at random bits of example code but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it.  What is the easiest and most efficient method to go back and forth between these images in one view?  The other problem I have is that I want there to be a button on the view which when pressed will allow the user to set the current image as the wallpaper/screensaver of the device.

I know this is an extremely easy answer for most, but I am a designer by trade and code is something I struggle with.

Thanks in advance!

Ian

Comment: this is a simple way to do this  
[simple way to do this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445897/image-array-ibaction-to-view-next-image-in-the-array/20628074#20628074

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have an array of imageNames;

eg.

```
NSArray * images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png",@"image4.png",@"image5.png",nil];
```

and then on next and previous button hits you can maintain an index variable
and you can set the image to the imageView

```
[yourImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:yourIndex]]];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav,

That works perfectly. Thanks. 

The only problem now is that I want a button on the screen which plays a sound based on the image. So say I have an image of a cat, a dog and a monkey in the array, I'd want the button to play the sound of the currently displayed animal. Is that easy done?

Comment: again you will need to store it in some array with same index, or you can go for database.

Answer (score 2):

```
//First you need to global variable.. maybe.. rs

@implementation FirstViewViewController{   
    int indexImage;  // <= important..
}

// This is your array.... <=

NSArray * images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png",@"image4.png",@"image5.png",nil];

//and sample next button do this...

- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {

    if ((indexImage+1) > arrayImages.count) {
        indexImage = 0;
    }
    self.imgLoadImage.image = [images objectAtIndex:indexImage];
    indexImage++;
}
// This guy "imgLoadImage" is an imageView on your screen  <=
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to play a sound with a selected image is going to be a little different then described above.

Your going to have to make an NSInteger (call it what ever you want). lets call it change.

So to change the sound with the image do it like this. every time you click the button - change += 1;

and then..

if (change == 1) {

--sound code here--

--change button image here--

}