# Image Array IBAction to view next image in the array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

Thanks to @JFoulkes I have got my app to show the first image in the array when clicking the next button.  However, when I click it again, it does not show the next image in the array.  This leads me to believe my IBAction for the next button is not quite right.

Here's the code I have so far...

In my .h file I have declared:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
NSArray *imageArray;
NSInteger currentImage;
```

And I also added:

```
-(IBAction) next;
```

In the .m file I have:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad;
{
imageArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], 
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], 
                  nil] retain];
}
```

This is my IBAction which is only ever showing the first image in the array (1.png) and when clicked again doesn't change the UIImageView to the second array image (2.png):

```
-(IBAction)next {

 if (currentImage + 1 == [imageArray count])
        currentImage = 0;
    UIImage *img = [imageArray objectAtIndex:currentImage];
    [imageView setImage:img]; 
   currentImage++;
}
```

Based on the code, how can I change the IBAction to successully iterate through the images in the array after ever click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your incrementing logic is broken, so the first click will do nothing and you can never reach the last image. If you would add a 3.png to your array, this would be a little more obvious. It might be instructive to step through the code, watching what it does at each step.

Correct incrementing logic would look something like this:

```
- (void)next {
    currentImage++;
    if (currentImage >= imageArray.count) currentImage = 0;
    UIImage *img = [imageArray objectAtIndex:currentImage];
    [imageView setImage:img];
}
```

Comment: Anomie - How would you code the previous action using this incrementing logic?

Comment: @Ian: `currentImage--`, of course, and then change the test to `if (currentImage < 0) currentImage = imageArray.count - 1;`

Comment: Ahh, I get it.  Finally, is it better to set the initial image I want to see when the view loads within the InterfaceBuilder or set it in the array I have in viewDidLoad?  If the latter, do I just define it as currentImage = 0;?

Comment: I'd recommend setting it from the array in viewDidLoad, as that way if you change the order of the images you won't be able to forget to correct it in the other place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

```
currentImage = 0;
```

This means the first image will always be loaded

You need to add a check to see if currentImage is larger than the imagearray:

```
if (currentImage +1 < [imageArray count])
{
    currentImage++;
    UIImage *img = [imageArray objectAtIndex:currentImage];
    [imageView setImage:img]; 
}
```

Comment: After 5 hours of trying, you helped me figure it out!  I used currentImage=0 because I thought it was part of the if statement and would cycle back to the first image at the end of the array.

Comment: This won't work quite right. I assume the view starts out displaying the image at index 0. After the first call, it will *still* be displaying the image at index 0. Only after the second call will it seem to work correctly. If combined with a similar implementation of `prev`, you'll probably find that changing directions gives you more problems.

Comment: Almost, it'll let you go one past the end and throw an NSRangeException. Change the `<=` to just `<` and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of images name it as images, initialize an integer "i".
In the view, create an imageView and two buttons(next and previous),
Use this code for the button action,

```
-(void)nextButton:(id)sender
{
if (i < (array.count-1))
{
    i=i+1;
     imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
}
}

-(void)previousButton:(id)sender
{
if(i >= 1)
{
    i=i-1;
    imageView.image=[images objectAtIndex:i];
}
}
```