# How to show next image on image view from image Array by clicking on button

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, ios4, xcode4.2

**I have image Array with two images out of that first image its showing properly on image View, for that i write code in view Did Load as`**

```
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
  NSLog(@"selected image:%@",urlString);
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *imagedata =[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imagedata];
[imgvw setImage:image];
```

**Now i need to show next image on clicking bar button for that code is** `

```
i=i+1;
NSLog(@"i=%d",i);
NSString *urlstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
NSLog(@"selected image:%@",urlstr);
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
NSData *imagedata =[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image1=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imagedata];
[imgvw setImage:image1];
```

**but crashes at line** `` `NSString *urlstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:i]]; ``
I didn't understand why it happens please suggest something?

Comment: @Hector 2012-06-16 10:53:11.313 Table View[1115:207] Image Array1=(
    "http://111.118.166.187/~petstest/product/1ff5f2527907ca86103288e1b7cc3446.jpg",
    "http://111.118.166.187/~petstest/product/480655b410d98a5cc3bef3927e786866.jpg"
)
2012-06-16 10:53:11.314 Table View[1115:207] selected image:http://111.118.166.187/~petstest/product/1ff5f2527907ca86103288e1b7cc3446.jpg
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: @Hector Sorry It is 2012-06-16 10:57:03.440 Table View[1135:207] selected image:http://111.118.166.187/~petstest/product/1ff5f2527907ca86103288e1b7cc3446.jpg
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
2012-06-16 10:57:15.500 Table View[1135:207] -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68809a0

Comment: View my answer in this link, which is pretty easy and simple  
[how to display the next and previous image by cliking a button][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445897/image-array-ibaction-to-view-next-image-in-the-array/20628074#20628074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i=0;

NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
SURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *imagedata =[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imagedata];
[imgvw setImage:image];


in button action event.

if(i<[imageArray1 count]-1)
{
i++;

NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
SURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *imagedata =[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imagedata];
[imgvw setImage:image];


}
else
{
// 
/NSLog(@" you reach the last items ");

}
```

Comment: Senthilkumar it crashing at line if(i<[imageArray1 count]-1)

Comment: before that if statement int countval=[imageArray1 count]-1; and check if(i<countvak)

Comment: And if i write on button action event as

Comment: NSLog(@"image Array count=%@",[imageArray1 count]);
    if(i<[imageArray1 count]-1)
    {
        i++;
        NSLog(@"int i=%d",i);
        NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData *imagedata =[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imagedata];
        [imgvw setImage:image]   }
    else
    {
        // 
        NSLog(@" you reach the last items ");   
    }
it crashes at NSLog(@"image Array count=%@",[imageArray1 count]);

Comment: yes inside the button action function you set these code from if statement and else

Comment: first line of nslog put %d instead of %@

Comment: Senthilkumar i tried this in view did load imageArray2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:imageArray1];
    NSLog(@"image Array 2=%@",imageArray2); and used in button action instead of imageArray1 as int countval=[imageArray2 count]-1;  and so on .. now it works but i didn't understand how? Any way Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

Declare `int i;` in yourviewcontroller.h file

i = 0; in   `viewDidLoad` method

You implement code when you pressed button.

```
 int noOfImages = [imageArray1 count];

    if(++i< noofImages){

    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
    SURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *imagedata =[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imagedata];
    [imgvw setImage:image];

    }
    else
    {
    i =0;
    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
    SURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *imagedata =[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imagedata];
    [imgvw setImage:image];
    }
```

Comment: Prasad it crashes and in log it says 2012-06-16 10:57:03.438 Table View[1135:207] Image Array1=(
    "http://111.118.166.187/~petstest/product/1ff5f2527907ca86103288e1b7cc3446.jpg",
    "http://111.118.166.187/~petstest/product/480655b410d98a5cc3bef3927e786866.jpg"
)
2012-06-16 10:57:03.440 Table View[1135:207] selected image:http://111.118.166.187/~petstest/product/1ff5f2527907ca86103288e1b7cc3446.jpg
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
2012-06-16 10:57:15.500 Table View[1135:207] -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68809a0